# Saving Byte Array Returns Null Reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, file-upload, arrays

I'm trying to save my `Photo` class that has a `byte[] File` field. When trying to save it using context is throws the error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

But when debugging I can see that it is not null. I can see all of the properties of the the class including the values in the byte array.

```
 public class PhotoRepository 
    {
        private static BlogContext _ctx;

        public PhotoRepository()
        {
            _ctx = new BlogContext();
        }

        public static void Save(Photo p)
        {
            _ctx.Photos.Add(p);
            _ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

controller

```
 public class PhotoController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            using (var ctx = new BlogContext())
            {
                return View(ctx.Photos.AsEnumerable());
            }
        }

        public ActionResult Upload()
        {
            return View(new Photo());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Upload(PhotoViewModel model)
        {
            var photo =  new Photo();//Mapper.Map<PhotoViewModel, Photo>(model);
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                photo.AlternateText = model.AlternateText;
                photo.Description = model.Description;
                photo.File = MapStreamToFile(model.File);
                photo.Name = model.Name;
                PhotoRepository.Save(photo);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(photo);
        }

        public byte[] MapStreamToFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            using (var stream = file.InputStream)
            {
                var memoryStream = stream as MemoryStream;
                if (memoryStream == null)
                {
                    memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                    stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                }
                return memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

Photo

```
 public class Photo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public Byte[] File { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public string AlternateText { get; set; }
    }
```

PhotoViewModel

```
 public class PhotoViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public string AlternateText { get; set; }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: *Exactly what* returns a `null` or raises a NullReferenceException? Less code and more stack, please.

Comment: You realize that every time you create a new instance of `PhotoRepository` you will re-initialize that *static* field, right?  That seems like and error prone and confusing design to me

Comment: its not byte array  You are trying to use a reference variable who’s value is null.

Comment: @EdS. Ah, I just noticed. Or, more importantly here, perhaps, `_ctx` will *not* be set before an instance is created.

Comment: @pst: Yep, that too.  OP, either `_ctx` is `null` because you never create an instance of `PhotoRepository`, `_ctx.Photos` is `null`, or you are getting the exception in `_ctx.SaveChanges();`.  Initialize that static member statically (i.e., when you declare it).  You are going to run into weird problems relying on a constructor to initialize static data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that `_ctx` is null.  Notice that you declare it and `Save` `static`, but `_ctx` is only instantiates in `public PhotoRepository()`, which is the constructor.  As long as it should really be static, instantiate it statically instead of in the constructor:

```
 public static class PhotoRepository 
    {
        private static BlogContext _ctx = new BlogContext();

        public static void Save(Photo p)
        {
            _ctx.Photos.Add(p);
            _ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

I also changed the class to `static`, since I only see it contains static members.  This may not be correct if you intend more for this class.

Edit: (thanks @pst) I see from looking at your code more, I think this might really be a better design:

```
 public class PhotoRepository : IDisposable
    {
        private BlogContext _ctx = new BlogContext();

        public void Save(Photo p)
        {
            _ctx.Photos.Add(p);
            _ctx.SaveChanges();
        }

        void IDisposable.Dispose() { _ctx.Dispose(); }
    }
```

And then always be sure to dispose `PhotoRepository` when you're done with it.  The reason for my suggested change here is that `BlogContext` is disposable, and is used with `using` in another place.

Comment: Thanks that worked, I just removed the static property and created a new PhotoRepository before calling.

Comment: Ok, good.  Be sure to dispose things that are disposable as soon as you're done with them (see my second code snippet in the answer for an example of a disposable PhotoRepository).

Comment: Thanks I was wondering how to Implement IDisposable in this situation